# php regex preg_match less than character breaking code

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to put together a preg_match to spot the following pattern

<[alphanumericstring] id[space or nospace]=[space or nospace][doublequotes or single quotes]a text string[doublequotes or single quotes][space or nospace]>

So the code will recognise:
    
and

This works:
    `if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9] id\s*=\s*[\"\']".$variable."\s*[\"\']\s*>/i", $document_content))`

But it stops working as soon as I add the first '<' like this:
    `if (preg_match("/<[a-z0-9] id\s*=\s*[\"\']".$variable."\s*[\"\']\s*>/i", $document_content))`

I've tried it as < as well. The final '>' doesn't cause any issues but is there some special way the '<' should be entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. For spaces use an actual space ( ) character.  \s will match tabs and line-breaks, too
2. Use ? for optional (1 or 0 instances).  * means 0 or more instances
3. Escape your tag open/close.  PCRE supports named params using LT/GT syntax.

Try this:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/\\<[a-z0-9]+ id ?= ?[\"']{$variable} ?[\"'] ?\\>/i", $document_content))
```

Comment: On reflection there were some mistakes in the way I phrased the question. For example between 'id' and '=' there may be nospace|space(s)|tab(s)|linebreak and hence my use of \s*. So I kept the \s* parts but adjusted as you suggested and works spot on! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
/\<[a-z0-9]+\sid\s?\=\s?(?:'|")$YOUR_VARIABLE_STRING(?:'|")\s?\>/g
```

Try using this one. ( Made with http://regexr.com/ )